# Turn off indent eclipse C/C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I NEED to turn off auto-indent on Eclipse for C/C++ coding. It DRIVES ME NUTS to be fighting with the editor constantly for the position of the text cursor.

This is a common question, but the standard answer does not appear to work on Kepler with C/C++ extentions, so perhaps it got "unfixed"???

The standard answer I saw was to go to preferences->C/C++->editor->typing and uncheck "automatically indent" new lines and braces.

The behavior is that entering new line causes the cursor to be aligned on the new line with the block above. I want newline to end up flush left.

Thanks,

Scott Franco

Comment: Note that this "automatic cursor position" seems to be active in general in the editor. For example, hitting the "start of line" key also does this in an indented line.

Comment: The 'start of line' effect can be turned off by going to "preferences -> general -> editors -> text editors" and then un-ticking "smart caret positioning at line start and end". But the auto-indent on new line still seems to occur.

Comment: Ok, yes, I turned that off, and yes, it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try per project settings.</s>

C/C++ General > Formatter > Edit...

Indentation Tab

Uncheck everything.

or

Eclipse wide

Window > Preferences

C/C++ > Code Style > Formatter > Edit...

Indentation Tab

Uncheck everything.

You can't unless you join the dev team http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/developers.php and make the change yourself.

Comment: Done in the "active profile", does not change the behavior. Thanks anyways (it says you cannot change it unless you copy to a new profile, so I did that).

Comment: I do notice that after doing this, the "start of line" key now actually goes to the start of line, not the indent.

Comment: And after playing around on the eclipse bug site, this seems to be the winning answer. Not only don't they consider it a problem, but they are tired of arguing about it -- based on several previous bugs filed. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: its a feature, notgonna fix it. It happens even if you call up a plain text editor. Eclipse has bugs filed against it by others that turned into long arguments. The developers went google on it [1]

[1] "went google": Our way or the highway. We are smart, you don't work at google, so obviously you are not. Next.